# How do I launch the recent apps menu in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to launch the menu that shows the recently used apps.

I've tried looking at logcat while hitting the button hoping there was some intent I could launch but no luck.

I know that on some phones it is a dedicated button and it can also happen by long-pressing the home button. Is there any way that I can launch it programmatically?

EDIT: Updated the title to be more accurate

Comment: Your title says simulate, but your post says you want to actually launch the recent apps screen... which is it?

Comment: I just want to launch the menu. That could involve simulating the keypress OR using an intent. Not sure what is possible

Comment: Give base/core/java/android/app/ActivityManager.java a look, I think that might have it in there. Just a guess though.

Comment: this question asks the same thing with better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267482/android-programmatically-open-recent-apps-dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible (mostly due to the many ways this is handled between the various esoteric Android OSs). However, you could get a list of running processes and make your own recent apps list. (Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278895/how-to-check-current-running-applications-in-android) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11174402/1438733) will help you.)

Comment: I was worried that would be the case. I know you can inject the home button press. I was hoping that if you couldn't launch it via an intent then you could simulate a long press of the home button.

Comment: Would it be possible if I limit the version of android to >3 or even >4?

Comment: I'm afraid not. There is a recent apps feature in Android 2.x (hold home button), and a limited feature in 3.x (no eliminating tasks), then the fully-featured version seen in 4.x. Unfortunately, these are controlled exclusively by the OS. It ***may*** be possible with rooting; I can't speak to that experience.

Comment: I'll give credit here since I also don't see a way to do this. I'll post back if I ever find out anything to the contrary

Comment: @BoredAndroidDeveloper Sounds good! I'm always happy to be proven wrong in favor of new knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

When you press "Recent Apps" button, the logcat will output following message:

```
568-716/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=com.android.systemui.recent.action.TOGGLE_RECENTS flg=0x10800000 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recent.RecentsActivity} from pid 627
    --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
568-582/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.android.systemui/.recent.RecentsActivity: +215ms
```

So, we can simulate of this operation by programmatically. (Don't forget to set the flags to 0x10800000):

```
Intent intent = new Intent ("com.android.systemui.recent.action.TOGGLE_RECENTS");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.systemui", "com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity"));
startActivity (intent);
```

For more infomation about `RecentsActivity`, please read the source code [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/recent/RecentsActivity.java).

Comment: I gave you an upvote - but I was looking for a way to do it on any device and this is dependent on stock android. I don't think there is a global way to do this without root or special permissions on all devices.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But if you want to find a global way, I think you can try to send a keypad KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH to invoke the RecentsActivity.

Answer (score 3):

just like what @Floerm post, this piece of code only work below android N , android N has change IStatusBarService api, we can't access like this.

```
private void openRecentApps() {
try {
    Class serviceManagerClass = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
    Method getService = serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
    IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerClass, "statusbar");
    Class statusBarClass = Class.forName(retbinder.getInterfaceDescriptor());
    Object statusBarObject = statusBarClass.getClasses()[0].getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class).invoke(null, new Object[]{retbinder});
    Method clearAll = statusBarClass.getMethod("toggleRecentApps");
    clearAll.setAccessible(true);
    clearAll.invoke(statusBarObject);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

If you want to launch the recent apps in Android N, you need to use AccessibilityService.

```
accessibilityService.performGlobalAction(AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_RECENTS);
```

Comment: Works perfectly on Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 5.0.1).