# Android: Programmatically open "Recent Apps" dialog

Tags: android

I would like to be able to open the "Recent Apps" dialog from my application. This is the dialog that is opened by long-pressing the home button. I am programming for Android 4.1 or earlier. I found a way to do it by implementing a custom AccessibilityService and calling AccessibilityService.performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_RECENTS), but this requires enabling accessibility on the phone, which is not very desirable. Is there any other way to open this dialog from an app?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot access that. However, it isn't super hard to roll your own. The [getRecentTasks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks%28int,%20int%29) method returns a list of recently run apps. Simply take the list and add your own UI to it.

One advantage to this is that the default one, at least on older versions of Android, only shows you about 8 apps.  If you roll your own can show as many as you want.

Comment: remember that some vendors modifies recent apps dialog, so your dialog wont look similar for those users.

Comment: @Leonidos True, but its the best solution I've been able to come up with without using the `AccessibilityService`.

Comment: Also note that these API's are meant for debugging only. I think they cause performance issues if used wrongly. Google Inc does not want devs to [use it in production code](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_rn=1&gs_ri=serp&pq=cats&cp=9&gs_id=7i&xhr=t&q=ocelot+kittens&client=firefox-aurora&hs=sDe&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.aGc&biw=1192&bih=645&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=X4T-UMSxDq2gigeMg4GwDw).

Comment: It is possible, check out my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, the method is deprecated as of API 21. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks(int,%20int)

Comment: Not alone deprecated but also returns only the current running app (size: 1)

Answer (score 38):

**This code won't work on Nougat or later**

It is possible to trigger the recent apps activity.

The StatusBarManagerService implements an public method which you can use through reflection.

You can use the following code:

```
Class serviceManagerClass = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
Method getService = serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(serviceManagerClass, "statusbar");
Class statusBarClass = Class.forName(retbinder.getInterfaceDescriptor());
Object statusBarObject = statusBarClass.getClasses()[0].getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class).invoke(null, new Object[] { retbinder });
Method clearAll = statusBarClass.getMethod("toggleRecentApps");
clearAll.setAccessible(true);
clearAll.invoke(statusBarObject);
```

Have fun

Comment: Using reflection is generally a bad idea as there is no guarantee that it works, or will continue to work on all versions of Android.

Comment: If using the above code, be sure to wrap it in a `try / catch`

Comment: The above code is not working for Android2.2 & 2.3, is there any other alternative way to make it work.

Comment: @Sathish Yeah, in Android < 3.0, the recent apps are shown in an dialog. (http://androidxref.com/2.3.6/xref/frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/RecentApplicationsDialog.java) AFAIK you cannot launch this.

Comment: @IonAalbers Is there a way to retrieve the screenshots of the recent apps the OS took when it was going into pause mode?

Comment: This really works! Thanks :)

Is there a way to clear the recent app list (without opening it)?

Comment: @IonAalbers , if you can explain this code snippet in detail, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Just wrap the code in a try/catch and it should work. Kuddos to your skills!!

Comment: This code is not work in nought, it's show error java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: toggleRecentApps [], Please help if anyone solve this problem

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using the **TOGGLE_RECENTS** Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent ("com.android.systemui.recent.action.TOGGLE_RECENTS");
intent.setComponent (new ComponentName ("com.android.systemui", "com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity"));
startActivity (intent);
```

> **Note** Package would be changed basis on Api level. [**See here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773533/3496570)

```
Android 4.1: "com.android.internal.policy.impl.RecentApplicationsDialog"
Android 4.2 - 4.4: "com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsActivity"
Android 5.0 - 7.1: "com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity" ("s" letter was added)
```

Comment: Thanks; this worked on Android 5.1.1 for me. However, the resulting activity looked different to the normal Android 5 one. Also, I think you missed a closing parenthesis on your second line.

Comment: for some the package changes to com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity

Comment: Got this issue
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=com.android.systemui.recent.action.TOGGLE_RECENTS cmp=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity