# how can I get the listview of recent activities without long press home key

Tags: android, android-launcher

Recently, I am coding the android launcher.

I found a function in Nova Launcher and Apex Launcher, which can show the views of recent tasks by touching a button without a long press on the home key.

I'd like to get it, but who can tell me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

```
performGlobalAction(int Action)
GLOBAL_ACTION_RECENTS
```

in android API documentation [here]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#performGlobalAction(int)

Alright, I think i found a solution for real this time, Check this thread at [here] : 
[Android: Programmatically open "Recent Apps" dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267482/android-programmatically-open-recent-apps-dialog)

Comment: Thank you,I read the docs just a moment ago.But now,I have two questions:
One,how can I get the instance to use the method? Another one,the method appears in API 16,but I want to match the API 14 in my app.

Comment: Oh,no,it means I can't access unless use my own UI , right? Anyway else?