# Android: programmatically open Overview/Recents screen in API 24+

Tags: android

I am trying to open the Overview/Recents screen in Android. From [Android: Programmatically open "Recent Apps" dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267482/android-programmatically-open-recent-apps-dialog/30579544#30579544), I can use the following code:

```
try {
    Class serviceManagerClass = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
    Method getService = serviceManagerClass.getMethod("getService", String.class);
    IBinder retbinder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(null, "statusbar");
    Class statusBarClass = Class.forName(retbinder.getInterfaceDescriptor());
    Object statusBarObject = statusBarClass.getClasses()[0]
            .getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class).invoke(null, retbinder);
    Method toggleRecentApps = statusBarClass.getMethod("toggleRecentApps");
    toggleRecentApps.setAccessible(true);
    toggleRecentApps.invoke(statusBarObject);
} catch (InvocationTargetException| NoSuchMethodException | RemoteException | IllegalAccessException   | ClassNotFoundException e){
    handleError(e);
}
```

However, `toggleRecentApps()` is [no longer in IStatusBarService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/statusbar/IStatusBarService.aidl) since Nougat, and it causes a NoSuchMethodException.

Is there any other way (excluding AccessibilityService) that can be used to open the Overview/Recents screen?

---

**EDIT**: The class that implements IStatusBarService seems to be [StatusBarManagerService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/statusbar/StatusBarManagerService.java). However, calling `statusBarObject.getClass().getCanonicalName()` returns `com.android.internal.statusbar.IStatusBarService.Stub.Proxy`, so getting an `IStatusBar` (which does implement `toggleRecentApps()`) through the private field `mBar` doesn't seem to be a working way to get it.

---

**EDIT 2**: Seeing that StatusBarManagerInternal.java is an interface that contains `void toggleRecentApps()`, I tried to find its implementation, which I found in `StatusBarManagerService`:

```
private final StatusBarManagerInternal mInternalService = new StatusBarManagerInternal() { ... }
```

So it's an anonymous class in StatusManagerService. >:(.

However, I also found:

```
/**
 * Construct the service, add the status bar view to the window manager
 */
public StatusBarManagerService(Context context, WindowManagerService windowManager) {
    mContext = context;
    mWindowManager = windowManager;

    LocalServices.addService(StatusBarManagerInternal.class, mInternalService);
}
```

So it apparently registers it in `LocalServices`, which in turn manages it in an `ArrayMap`:

```
private static final ArrayMap<Class<?>, Object> sLocalServiceObjects =
        new ArrayMap<Class<?>, Object>();
```

Therefore, I tried to access it:

```
try {
    Field services = Class.forName("com.android.server.LocalServices")
            .getDeclaredField("sLocalServiceObjects");
    services.setAccessible(true);
    ArrayMap<Class<?>, Object> serviceMap = (ArrayMap<Class<?>, Object>) services.get(null);
    Set<Map.Entry<Class<?>, Object>> serviceSet = serviceMap.entrySet();

    for (Map.Entry<Class<?>, Object> serviceEntry : serviceSet) {
        if (serviceEntry.getKey().isInterface()) {
            if ("com.android.server.statusbar.StatusBarManagerInternal"
                    .equals(serviceEntry.getKey().getName())) {
                Object statusBarInternalObject = serviceEntry.getValue();
                Class statusBarInternalClass = serviceEntry.getKey();
                Method openRecents = statusBarInternalClass.getMethod("toggleRecentApps");
                openRecents.setAccessible(true);
                openRecents.invoke(statusBarInternalObject);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    handleError(e);
}
```

However:

```
/**
 * This class is used in a similar way as ServiceManager, except the services registered here
 * are not Binder objects and are only available in the same process.
 *
 * Once all services are converted to the SystemService interface, this class can be absorbed
 * into SystemServiceManager.
 *
 * {@hide}
 */
```

Alas, I have to be in the SystemUI process (or so it seems) to be able to access it. (Effectively, the `ArrayMap` is empty, rendering my attempt useless.)

Any guidance on how to proceed from here would be appreciated.

Comment: That is the problem with methods which are invoked via reflection the APIs can change.

Comment: That method is also not necessarily available on any given device, as device manufacturers and custom ROM developers are welcome to modify Android internals as they see fit.

Comment: @CommonsWare true, but I at least need it to work on stock Android.

Comment: Ok, just made another attempt at this and failed. Is there I can access the same map that is holding the `StatusBarInternal`? Or someway to access that `StatusBarInternal` instance? Or at least an `IStatusBar`?

Answer (score 4):

Create service extended from `AccessibilityService`:

```
class ExampleAccessService:AccessibilityService() {
    override fun onInterrupt() {
    }

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
    }

    fun doAction(){
        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_RECENTS)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_HOME)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_POWER_DIALOG)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_QUICK_SETTINGS)
//        performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_TOGGLE_SPLIT_SCREEN)
    }
}
```

*Call `doAction()` where you want action*

Add to `Manifest`:

```
<application
...
    <service
        android:name=".ExampleAccessService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
        android:label="Name of servise" // it will be viewed in Settings->Accessibility->Services
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config"/>
    </service>
...
</application>
```

**accessibility_service_config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="false"
    android:description="your description"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:packageNames="your app package, ex: ex: com.example.android"
    android:settingsActivity="your settings activity ex: com.example.android.MainActivity" />
```

for more info look at [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html](http://developer.android.com)

Comment: In short: I've tried the solution and can not get the action, probably missing some initialization.

Comment: Did you turn on Accessibility service on device? Settings -> Accessibility -> Services-> your service name (at top of screen) -> turn it on

Comment: public class ExampleAccessService extends AccessibilityService
{private static ExampleAccessService instance;@Override
protected void onServiceConnected(){super.onServiceConnected();instance=this;}@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){instance=null;return super.onUnbind(intent);}@Override
public void onInterrupt(){}@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event){}
public static ExampleAccessService getInstance(){return instance;}@RequiresApi(api=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public void openRecents(){performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_RECENTS);}}